# How do I get listofLists to be defined in this function? python! When put in another function still does not work?

Tags: python

How can I initialize listofLists to be defined? When I tried to put it as an empty list (listofLists = []) in a different function and run it through main() it still did not work. I'm trying to change a 2D list to a 1D list I just cannot define listofLists. 
This is the code i'm trying: (python 3.7)

```
def convert2list(listofLists):
    new_list = []

    for list in listofLists:
        new_list += list
    return new_list
```

Comment: Each item in `listofLists` **must** be a list.  That is the only want to append them to `new_list`.

Comment: How are you calling convert2list? If I try your code with `convert2list([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])`, I get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. The argument to `convert2list` is a list containing two elements, the lists [1,2,3] and [4,5,6]. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: I screwed up some of my other list names in the file that I got mixed up, thank you for helping me clarify!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.

```
>>> listofLists = [[1,2], [], [3,4,5]]
>>> convert2list(listofLists)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Here is another way:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> listofLists = [[1,2], [], [3,4,5]]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*listofLists))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```